# MYSQL Many-to-many select (chats, latest message, username) in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select a list of the user's chats in one statement, together with each chats latest message and the massage's sender's name.

The abstract problem is:
Ever chat can have multiple participating users. 
A message is sent to a "chat", not a specific user.

These are the tables I came up with

```
TABLE users (id, username)
TABLE chats (id)
TABLE messages (id, message, chat_id, user_id)
```

And lastly a many-to-many relation table between chats and participants

```
TABLE chats_users (chat_id,user_id)
```

I  want to list all the chats a certain user participates in, together with the latest message and it's sender's username.
How would I go about that in one statement?

Im running Mysql 5.0.9 and php 7.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: A *on cu.user_id = u.id* by id or name?

Comment: i have the user_id, and want to list all his chats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
select max(m.id) id
from chats_users cu
inner join users u on cu.user_id = u.id
inner join messages m on m.chat_id = cu.chat_id
where cu.chat_id in (select chat_id from chats_users where user_id = ?) 
group by cu.chat_id
```

returns the last messages of all the chats that *a certain user participates*.
Use it in this query:

```
select m.chat_id, m.message, u.username
from messages m inner join users u
on u.id = m.user_id
where m.id in ( 
  select max(m.id) id
  from chats_users cu
  inner join users u on cu.user_id = u.id
  inner join messages m on m.chat_id = cu.chat_id
  where cu.chat_id in (select chat_id from chats_users where user_id = ?) 
  group by cu.chat_id
)
```

to get the details of these messages.

Comment: damn! thank you. never would have figured that out myself